# How to show nested ViewModel from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, tag-helpers

I have the following ViewModel

```
 public class ProductsViewModel
 {
        public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products;

        public ProductViewModel Product;
 }
```

which implements

```
public class ProductViewModel 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following form

```
    <input asp-for="@Model.Product.Name" />
    <label>Description</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Product.Description" />
    <label>Value</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Product.Value" />
```

I implement this action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Product model)
        {
            await productService.Create(model.Product.Name, model.Product.Description, model.Product.Value);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

but the data I receive is null because the Action expects Product.Name, Product.Description, Product.Value.
Any idea how to receive the data from my View?

Fixed. This works

```
public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
```

but I don't like this mess. If someone has better solution?

Comment: Hi  @jetfuel,If it works, please feel free to [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) useful answers, which will help others facing same issue to find solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your binding method is not wrong, you just forgot to add `get and set` to your `ViewModel`.

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you It worked (: So apparently my post request can't bind the data into the nested ProductViewModel Product without {get; set;}